# How to prevent "Last Login:" message from showing up when using sftp?

Tags: ssh, sftp, openssh, motd

In Ubuntu GNU/Linux 12.04, I have a user `johndoe` that is part of an `sftponly` group, set up to `sftp` to a `chroot` jail using

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

at the end of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. All components of the user's `home` directory are `root`-owned directories that are not writeable by any other user or group, as explained in `man sshd_config` (under `ChrootDirectory`). Inside his `chroot` jail, there is a writeable directory `files`:

```
sudo groupadd sftponly    
sudo mkdir -p /home/sftponly/johndoe/files
sudo useradd -d /home/sftponly/johndoe -g sftponly -s /usr/sbin/nologin johndoe
sudo chmod go-w /home/sftponly/{,johndoe}
sudo chown johndoe:sftponly /home/sftponly/johndoe/files
sudo chmod ug+rwX /home/sftponly/johndoe/files
```

(Setting the shell to `/bin/false` did not work with either `ssh` or `sftp`. With `nologin` as the shell `ssh` connects, shows "MOTD", and then disconnects, which is the expected behavior.)

But `sftp` fails with the message `Received message too long 1416128883`. I know this failure is caused by "MOTD" (Message Of The Day), as `sftp` expects a "clean login." I have tried disabling all "MOTD" pieces on the server using the following, with (**these results**):

- Adding `PrintLastLog no` and `PrintMotd no` to the end of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and restarting `ssh` using `restart ssh`. (**No effect**. Testing with `ssh` shows both "MOTD" and "Last Login:".)
- Commenting out `session    optional     pam_motd.so` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. (**Prevents MOTD**. But there is no corresponding entry for "LastLog" so, testing with `ssh`, "Last Login:" still shows up and hence **`sftp` still fails**.)
- Commenting out `session    optional   pam_lastlog.so` and `session    optional   pam_motd.so` in `/etc/pam.d/login`. (**No effect**. Testing with `ssh` shows both MOTD and "Last Login:".)
- Creating the `.hushlogin` file on the client using `touch ~/.hushlogin`. (**No effect**.)

I am out of ideas. Where else may this "Last Login:" message be coming from and how can it be disabled (ideally only for `sftp` and not for `ssh` logins, but, I imagine as `sftp` uses `ssh`, the message is going to be there either for both or none)?

Comment: Your question still appears as an unanswered question.
Post your answer and accept it (or accpt another answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typo on my part was the cause of the unreasonable behavior I was experiencing above. It is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (corresponding to the `ssh` daemon) that must be edited, not `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (corresponding to the `ssh` client). I leave this question here in case it may help someone else.

Comment: I'll add to this that I had to edit the line `PrintLastLog yes` to `no` instead. I'm not sure what else this setting might change, but it doesn't print the message anymore.

Answer (score 2):

On my system it came from Pam.

`/etc/pam.d/postlogin` to be exact.

I got rid of the message by commenting out the existing lines and adding:

```
session     optional      pam_lastlog.so silent
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering /etc/motd in scripts I use (this example is for program git)
`git pull 2>&1 | grep -vF -f ~/bin/remote.motd | egrep -v "^$|^  $"`
The file ~/bin/remote.motd is a copy-paste of the motd given by the remote system.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted /var/log/lastlog and the "Last login" message was gone forever. Worked with all distros I tested: Ubuntu and SUSE.

How did I come to this idea?

```
which login
strings /bin/login | grep last
```

Comment: But this has the unwanted side effect of making `lastlog` unusable on the server.